# USB GCC Development Environment with Libraries

Tags: gcc, linker, g++, usb

I'm trying to get something of an environment on a usb stick to develop C++ code in. I plan to use other computers, most of the time linux, to work on this from a command line using g++ and make.

The problem is I need to use some libraries, like Lua and OpenGL, which the computers don't have. I cannot add them to the normal directories, I do not have root on these computers. Most of the solutions I've found involve putting things in /usr/lib/ and the like, but I cannot do that. I've also attempted adding options like '-L/media//lib', which is where they are kept, and it didn't work. When compiling, I get the same errors I got when first switching to an OS with the libraries not installed.

Is there somewhere on the computer outside of /usr/ I can put them, or a way to make gcc 'see' them?

Comment: how did -L/media/lib not work?

Comment: It gave the same exact errors when I did that, which are not encountered when I compile on my computer, with the libraries in /usr/lib/.

Comment: let's try this again - HOW did it not work (examples/output/error messages/......)

Comment: show your makefile, your gcc line, how your usb stick is laid out, ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need more than the libraries to be able to compile code utilizing those libraries. (I'm assuming Linux here, things might be slightly different on e.g. OSX,BSDs,Cygwin,Mingw..)

### Libraries

For development you need these 3 things when your code uses a library:

- The library header files, .h files
- The library development files, libXXX.so or libXXX.a typically
- The library runtime files , libXXX.so.Y where Y is a version number. These are not needed if you statically link in the library.

You seem to be missing the header files (?) Add them to your usb stick, say under /media/include

### Development

- Use (e.g.) the compiler flag `-I/media/include` when compiling source code to refer to a non-standard location of header files.
- Use the compiler/linker flag `-L/media/lib` to refer to non-standard location of libraries.

You might be missing the first step.

### Running

For dynamically linked libraries, the system will load those only from default locations, typically /lib/ , /usr/lib/

Learn the `ldd` tool to help debug this step.

You need to tell the system where to load additional libraries when you're running a program, here's 3 alternatives:

- Systemwide: Edit /etc/ld.so.conf and add /media/libs there. Run `ldconfig -a` afterwards.
- Local, to the current shell only. set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to refer to /media/lib, run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/media/lib`
- Executable: Hardcode the non-standard library path in the executable. You add this to the linking step when creating your executable: `-Wl,-rpath,/media/lib`

### Etc.

There could be other reasons things are not working out, if so,
show us the output of ls -l /media/libs , and where you put the library header files, the command line you use to compile/link, and the exact errors you get.

- Missing the headers and/or development libraries (for dynamic libraries there is usually a symlink from a libXXX.so to a libXXX.so.Y , the linker needs the libXXX.so , it will not look directly at  libXXX.so.Y)
- using libraries not compatible with your current OS/architecture. (libraries compiled on one linux distro is often not compatible with another distro, or even another minor version of the same distro)
- using an usb stick with a FAT32 filesystem, you'll get in trouble with symlinks..